# Where could I get a sports fiction short story published?

Tags: short-story, publishing

I've found Stymie magazine, but are there any other magazines devoted primarily to sports themed fiction writing? I think my story stands on its own as it is more about the relationship between the various characters than the actual sport, but it takes place entirely in a sporting context so those with an interest in sport may find it more entertaining. 
If not, are there any other magazines, etc. that would publish sports fiction even if they are not a sports themed publication?

Answer (score 1):

These are some  countrywise sport fiction magazines in which you can publish sports fiction short stories :

**For US** :

- 1) Ace Sports (Monthly)     2) The All-America Sports Magazine
  3) Best Sports (Magazine)   4) Big Sports Magazine
  5) Dime Sport(s) Magazine

**For UK** :

- Boxing Shorts
- Racing Shorts

**For Australia** :

- Action Sports Fiction (*)
- Sports Novels Magazine (Australia) (*)

**For Canada** :

- College Sports
- Exciting Sports (Canada) (*)
- New Sports Magazine (Canada) (*)
- Sport Story Magazine (Canada) (*)